# Complex object in 3d opengl Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, blender

I am given a task of making some complex 3d object in opengl android.Earlier I have worked only on the primitive objects of opengl using nehe tutorials.
I have googled and found that Blender is used to make 3d object and then it is imported in android project .But I cant get HOW?

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to do it is to export your objects in the OBJ format (it describes vertices of an object). You can then easily make your own OBJ reader (or use an existing one) and pass the vertices to OpenGL.

Else, don't reinvent the wheel and use a library that already does this for you (libgdx for instance).

Answer (score 0):

> ... then it
>   is imported in android project

Actually it's usually not *imported* but simply load from file by the target application. There are some export scripts for Blender that emit C code or even write out OpenGL calls; DON'T use them, they'll just mess up your program.

There are some good libraries for 3D object storage, like [OpenCTM](http://openctm.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Hi @datenwolf, I just started getting my hands on 3D files in Android, since I already used OpenCTM with WebGL on web apps I would like to go forward in using it as a 3D file format even on Android but I can't find so much info on the internet. I found [JOpenCTM](https://github.com/Danny02/JOpenCTM) and I was able to load a file but I don't understand how to go forward (there is not much documentation about JOpenCTM). I know that it is not how SO works, but could you kindly point me in the right direction with some answere here or some tutorial (if you know one)?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an array of floats that represent your vertices/normals, like so:

```
float [ ]  vertices = {
VertexX, VertexY, VertexZ, NormalX, NormalY, NormalZ,
VertexX, VertexY, VertexZ, NormalX, NormalY, NormalZ,
VertexX, VertexY, VertexZ, NormalX, NormalY, NormalZ,
VertexX, VertexY, VertexZ, NormalX, NormalY, NormalZ,
..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ...,
};
```

Where each face has three unique vertex lines associated with it. Once you have this array built from an OBJ file or whatever format you want, using code that you'll have to figure out, you can render it by doing the following:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(vertices[0])*6, &vertices[0]);
glNormalPoitner(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(vertices[0])*6, &vertices[3]);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices);
```

See this [Wikipedia page on the OBJ format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) for reference on how the obj file is laid out. Parsing the file is pretty straightforward once you understand the format.